# (mysql) Database replication between 2 DB while 3rd DB as backup

Tags: mysql, replication, backup

I am not an advanced DB admin or designer. I am sure there are articles on this kind of scenario, probably too many. So I got confused and not sure which solution is appropriate/best for me.

I am setting up two DB on different region. Users will access/write to the nearest one. So these 2 DB should be 100% identical. Any insert, update, delete on a DB replicate same on the other instantly.
(better if table structure on a DB can also alter other DB table)

See the attached diagram. Clients can use any of these DBs.

There is the 3rd DB. Clients won't ever access it or write to it. 
It's for backup purposes only.
Any changes but "delete" from other DB will be replicate to this one.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: anyone ?? I'd really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dual-Master, where you write to both masters, is full of problems.  You need to carefully set the two `auto_increment_*` "variables".  You need to make sure users cannot insert the same `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` values into different masters.  If 'East' goes down, the Slave is hard to reconnect.  If a hurricane hits the East, you lose both the master and slave there.  Etc.

A slight improvement is "Dual-Master, Single writer".  That is, you have the configuration you described, but clients never write to more than one of the Masters.  The configuration is more stable, but the failover process is perhaps more complex.

Instead, consider Galera (in MariaDB or PXC), which solves many of the problems.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I didn't consider "auto-increment" issue when writing to both Masters. Whole point of Multi-master is the performance. With "single writer" users get advantage on "read" but not on "write" :(

I am not familiar with MariaDB at all but I have just spent few hours to read articles and youtube video on it.

Comment: I have some questions-
1) It seems MariaDB can upgrade existing MySQL DB. Does that mean, my PHP scripts don't need to be changed but can use same syntax (ie- $mysqli->query(SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1) etc) ?

2) I believe I need to add Galera plugin. I read somewhere it's not available for Windows platform. Is that correct? It'd be a headache for me as I am using Azure Win Server 2012 VMs.

3) Just double checking- MariaDB with Galera doesn't have auto-increment or similar issue when writing on multiple masters?

Comment: sorry, one more question- why can't I use Galera with MySQL? Why do I need MariaDB ?

Comment: Galera comes packaged with newer MariaDB releases.  With MySQL, you have to do a separate install, etc.  Galera takes care of `auto_increment_*` for you.  And it does a bunch of other things that you would otherwise have to do yourself (when doing Dual-Master).  PHP and it's mysqli* are compatible with MariaDB and Galera.  Read my [_Galera notes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera).  You are probably right about Galera not working on Windows.

Comment: Dual Master gives you virtually no performance boost -- all writes must be applied (via replication) to both machines.